# Sum of index matches for dynamic range of columns

Tags: excel

On `Sheet2` I am trying to sum the values in a row of a range on `Sheet1` over a dynamic range of columns based on a lookup value for the *from* column and a fixed variable for how many columns to right of that lookup value for the *to* column.

I am using INDEX-MATCH to find the *from* cell based on certain reference, INDEX-MATCH with a reference added to the column lookup to find the *to* column, and CELL to get the position rather than value of the results.

What I have is the following:

```
=SUM(
CELL("address",
INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$BA$36,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$4:$A$36),MATCH(D$3,Sheet1!$B$3:$BA$3,0)))
&":"&
CELL("address",
INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$BA$36,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$4:$A$36),MATCH(D$3,Sheet1!$B$3:$BA$3,0)+'Control Panel'!$C$2)))
```

`Control Panel!$C$2` is my variable for how many columns to the right of the *from* column I want the *to* column to be.

Obviously, this is not working. I suspect it's because the concatenated text in the SUM() reference the full file name rather than `'Sheet1'![from]:[to]`. Not sure if this is the case, but also can't figure out how to get just the A1 cell position for the *to*.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$BA$36,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$4:$A$36),MATCH(D$3,Sheet1!$B$3:$BA$3,0))):INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$BA$36,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$4:$A$36),MATCH(D$3,Sheet1!$B$3:$BA$3,0)+'Control Panel'!$C$2))
```

Literally just needed a colon between the two index-matches. Still not sure why this works, as the index-match should return a value.